# Session variable not getting displayed

Tags: django, session, session-variables, requestcontext

I print the session variable in base template as follows:

```
{% if request.session.user_id %}
Welcome {{ request.session.user_id }}, <a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a>
{% endif %}
```

**views.py**

```
def loginfun(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    errors = []
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            request.session['user_id'] = username
            return render_to_response('home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            #errors.append("Account Inactive")
            return render_to_response('home.html',{'errors':errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'registration'
)
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. i'm a newbie.

Comment: RequestContext problem solved but now the session variable is not getting displayed.

Comment: Where is the username parameter declared? I can only see you passing in user to the login method.

Comment: updated login method. do i need to post the whole of settings.py?

Comment: have you included `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` also what have you set as the `session` backend? If possible please share `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

`django.core.context_processors.request` is not in [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) by default so you don't have `{{ request }}` variable at all